# Inclusion of GRE score/completion on CV - under which heading?

Tags: cv

First of all, yes I know people have asked questions over whether or not to include the GRE score on here, and the answer is generally no. *If* you're already in a (US or Canada) grad school.

I would argue my case is different. I took the GRE less than a year ago and did well, with the plan to attend the grad school at Notre Dame. I'm from the UK and ended up heading to Germany to undertake a PhD. After the PhD (*if* I complete) there's a high likelihood I will apply for Postdoctoral / teaching positions in the US. So my question to you all is:

1. Let's say I've completed (or are on track to complete) my PhD by the time potential employers at universities or research institutions in the US see my application. Would they like to see / would it help their judgement of my aptitude if my GRE score was on there? [Regarding expiry of the scores, I sat the GRE in Spring 2019 and am scheduled to finish my PhD in Summer 2022; I don't remember the expiry time]. But in my mind, it might be good to simply include the fact that I sat and completed it.
2. Under which heading on my CV would I include it? Education, Qualifications, Advanced Training?

Comment: I would use the heading "standardized test scores". That is pretty much what they are. If you want to add Toefl etc. you can use that heading as well.

Comment: I highly doubt it will matter. A test score won't convey research potential, service, or approaches to teaching.

Comment: As someone who hires postdocs, I would think it really weird to see a resume with a GRE score on it. The only use for a GRE score is to get into graduate school. It has absolutely no value in evaluating whether or not you would be a good post-doc. That is what your PhD work is for.

Answer (score 5):

My feeling is that unless you did phenomenally well (well within top 5%), it would not be of much relevance to those looking at your application (the likely effect would be [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/that-s-not-saying-much)), and if you **did do** phenomenally well, then its inclusion could have the same effect as mentioning having an IQ score of 160 or more (something you'd probably not want to do, even if you did have such a score). Employers at universities or research institutions want to see evidence of teaching competence and/or research competence, not a high score on a test designed to measure your potential to do well in classwork, since presumably none of your duties will involve taking classes for a grade.